# saving data in JSON object and sending online

Tags: php, json

My idea is to have a contact form encode all the input data into a JSON file and then sending it somewhere, where I can access it with Google Spreadsheet, using [this method.](https://medium.com/@paulgambill/how-to-import-json-data-into-google-spreadsheets-in-less-than-5-minutes-a3fede1a014a#.3lzxlvtm2)

This is my current php part of the form:

```
<?php

$errors         = array();      
$data           = array();      

if (empty($_POST['name']))
    $errors['name'] = 'Name is required.';

if (empty($_POST['email']))
    $errors['email'] = 'Email is required.';

if (empty($_POST['superheroAlias']))
    $errors['superheroAlias'] = 'Superhero alias is required.';

if ( ! empty($errors)) {
    $data['success'] = false;
    $data['errors']  = $errors;
} else {

    $data['success'] = true;
    $data['message'] = 'Success!';}


   echo json_encode($data);
```

This displays the success message on the form, but that's it. Now I need to actually *do something* with the information. I tried to add a POST Email function, just to see if I actually get a mail..

```
$to = "email@email.com"; 
$from = $_POST['email']; 
$first_name = $_POST['name'];
$last_name = $_POST['name2'];
$subject = "Form submission";
$message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
$message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $first_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

$headers = "From:" . $from;
$headers2 = "From:" . $to;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2);
```

However, now I don't even see the success message and I am stuck at this point.

**1. Is there a reason why the mail does not send ?**

---

**2. How can I actually process the JSON object that I have (hopefully) generated with the echo json_encode($data); ?**

*I can provide the html and js parts of the form for better reference, if needed.*

Answer (score 0):

You should receive errors/warnings in your PHP error-log if you enabled it correctly.
Make sure you set an logfile path correctly in your webserver configuration.
Verify that display_errors = On is set in your php.ini configuration, along with error_reporting = E_ALL

If theres no mail being sent, you could possibly have to set up a SMTP service. Also, if you are on Linux, you could check the mail logs under /var/log/mail.log and see if any error occurred there.

If you wish to process the JSON data that you generate, you can just do an: `$jsonData = json_decode($data, TRUE);` and use it as an associate array as you were before encoding it.

Comment: ah, yes. You were right about SMTP service.. and thank you for reminding me that there is a php log file on the server - I have tried to use the php console in Chrome, lol.
So I've installed swift mail and got it all working! Now I'll try to deal with dealing with the JSON file.